# Are we able to store low energy positrons in a magnetic field for arbitrarily long time?

Tags: antimatter, elementary-particles

And if not, what prevents us? Is there a mathematical equation describing the loss rate?

Comment: How long were LEP runs? Based on the data I found around 2-3 hours... so that's already a lot longer than for anti-hydrogen. See figure 3 in "A Brief History of the LEP Collider" Ralph Aßmann, Mike Lamont and Steve Myers a for the LEP team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about a 'world record' in physics and not physics.

Comment: I'm not looking for a world record per se. I'm just curious about for how long it's possible to store positrons.

Comment: I guess it's going to depend on the quality of your vacuum. Also, if you can keep accelerating them they go too fast to annihilate even if they do occasionally interact. I suspect that the answer will be shorter for low energy positrons - although their low velocity may keep them from "finding" other particles, other particles will still find them - and they will annihilate when that happens.

Comment: @KyleKanos, achievements in experimental physics are  certainly part of physics and they are of interest to people visiting this site. Calling them "world records"  in derogatory sense does not contribute.